# fullpage.js silentMoveTo doesn't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I'm creating a fullpage.js site where I need to have the slides scroll in to view on a particular slide. Like this:

1
X2X
  3
  4

Where X2X is 3 slides, I want to land on the 2nd one so user can go left or right.

I am using `OnLeave` to call `silentMoveTo` but whatever I do doesn't seem to take effect:

```
onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction) {
        var params = {
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            direction: direction
        };
        //after leaving first section
        console.log("leaving...");
        if (origin.index == 0 && direction == "down") {
        // moves the slides to the 2nd slide
        console.log("fire after 1?");
        fullpage_api.silentMoveTo(1, 1);
        }
    }
```

But `silentMoveTo` doesn't work. Here's a CodePen https://codepen.io/thetwopct/pen/bZwyRw

Any tips to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the _sections_ are not indexed starting with 0, but with 1 …? So you need `fullpage_api.silentMoveTo(2, 1);` to slide to the 2nd slide in the 2nd section. (That does the sliding as intended, but causes the onLeave event to fire constantly - so you might have to modify `origin.index == 0` as well, that probably needs to check for == 1 then.)

Comment: Thanks! I played around with that, putting 2,1 seems to break it with JS error - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Comment: You need to figure out the right point to trigger this, currently it seems that performing this sliding action triggers the event, and that then wants to slide it again … as I said, the `if (origin.index == 0 && direction == "down")` probably needs modifying as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't need to do this via OnLeave/silentMoveTo, just add `active` class to the slide I wanted to show.

As per https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/522

Comment: That's the way! :)